# Query in Override of node.tpl

Tags: drupal-6

I have override a node.tpl and need some results from db using a query generated by views.
Here is the code which i used:

```
    <?php $res = db_query("SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title FROM node node LEFT JOIN content_field_is_popular node_data_field_is_popular ON node.vid
= node_data_field_is_popular.vid WHERE (node.type in ('article_thisweekend')) AND (UPPER(node_data_field_is_popular.field_is_popular_value)
= UPPER('yes'));");
    foreach($res as $reco){
        print ($reco->nid);
    }
    ?>
```

But I am not getting any results.
What I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt V. has good advice in that you should try to separate the view templates from the sql query logic.

For this specific example though, you need to use  `db_fetch_object` since `$res` just contains the
[database query result resource](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.pgsql.inc/function/db_query/6)

Instead of

```
 foreach($res as $reco){
    print ($reco->nid);
 }
```

Do

```
while ($reco = db_fetch_object($res)){
   print ($reco->nid);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's generally best to avoid putting queries directly in your template files. It's best to [separate logic and presentation](http://drupal.org/node/1965).

Instead, use a module to generate the content you need and pass that along to the theme layer. In this case, if you're already using the Views module to generate the query, let Views run it for you and pass off the data to a page or block display.

Otherwise, to debug the query, try running the query independent of the code, through something like phpMyAdmin or "[drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush) sqlq".